# Keeping my birthday private

Tags: apple-id, privacy

I was required to give my birthday when creating an Apple ID. How do I now keep this information private? I see it has appeared on my Google calendar and I am hoping it does not appear on my contacts' calendars as well.

Comment: Just enter a wrong one :-)

Comment: @patrix ??? are you suggesting cheating ?

Comment: I suggest to protect your privacy. How important is your exact birthday really for having an AppleID (as long as the year is correct)?

Comment: @patrix just kidding...I use you system anyway.

Comment: Are you saying you can't remove it from your gcal? Also, go to Address Book (or Contacts in Mountain Lion 10.8) and go to Preferences>Vcard(tab) and check the box that says "Enable private me card".

Answer (score 1):

Your birthday will be private. Read the privacy policy if you're concerned about it.

If your birthday appears in your calendar, it's probably because your birthday has been added to your private card in Address Book. There's an option to show birthdays in Calendar. However the birthdays are only showed to you, not your contacts.

Beware of entering an erroneous birth date. Apple can ask you your birthday to verify you're the actual owner of the Apple ID for security purpose. So if you enter a false birthday, be sure not to forget it.